# Difference between SLF4J UNBOUND and SLF4J BOUND TO NOP

Tags: java, slf4j

Can any one please provide the "what is the difference between `SLF4J UNBOUND` and `SLF4J BOUND TO NOP`".

I have gone through the **[slf4j manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)**
 but I didn't find the difference between these two concepts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe both are one and the same. If we don't specify any logging binding it is called as UNBOUND. In such cases it defaults to NOP logging. I think this you are referring to as BOUND TO NOP.

Looking at the output from the first example on sl4j manual it says,

`SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation` as it is not bound to any logging.